# Android httpUrlConnect with URL variable not working?

Tags: android

Im trying to implement some http functions in an android app (which I am slightly new to) and am having problems with passing a variable into a URL.

example:

```
onCreate() {
  String somevar = "http://127.0.0.1"
  urlConnectTest(somevar)
}

private static boolean urlConnectTest(String url) throws IOException {
    URL wwwurl = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) wwwurl.openConnection();
    urlConnection.connect();
    urlConnection.disconnect();
    return true;
}
```

urlConnectTest(somevar), does not work above... I get basically a timeout and an IOException with the above code,  and a packet is never sent to the server in question.

urlConnectTest("http://127.0.0.1") does work, though,  I get a packet to 127.0.0.1 and all is well.  But passing a variable to the function and using that never works for me.  Debug shows nothing different with the variable.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Edit:Minor update.

Comment: Add permission for your app

Comment: Network on main thread perhaps?  Check your logs.

Comment: Interesting,  I never caught it in the logs,  but its trying to send a packet to the wrong ip address.  And since this is all testing yes it is in the main thread,  so when it times out the app is locked up.  Debugging shows everything you expect so Im not sure where this other ip address is coming from.  I guess I need a packet trace off the phone now to understand what it is really doing.

Comment: Just a thought, try it in a worker thread, and see if you still get the wrong IP.  Network operations are not supported on the main thread, so that could result in unexpected behavior.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Comment: I actually intended on putting this in a service,  so ill get to moving it there.  Hopefully that will take care of it.

Comment: You never can use 127.0.0.1. If you use an emulator that should be 10.0.2.2. If you use a device it should be the ip address of the computer your server is running on.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 was an example.  I should of subbed for an rfc1918 address rather then localhost.

Comment: One last bit of info,  I moved this to a thread,  and the same issue happens.